# How to trigger a request from javascript to download a file from a backend

Tags: javascript, flask

I have a webserver that is using flask.

To download a file from the webServer, I have the following code:

```
@images_api_blueprint.route('/api/v1_2/download_file3', methods=['GET'])
def download_file3():
    zipFullFileName1 = './foo.zip'
    response1 = send_file(zipFullFileName1, as_attachment=True)
    return response1
```

If I type "http://localhost/api/v1_2/download_file3" in the browser, the file is downloaded - good!

But I need to trigger the download programatically from my client via javascript.
When I click on a button, I reach the code below, which triggers the same url as above,

```
this.downloadFile3 = function (layer, zipFilename) {
    let queryUrl = 'http://localhost/api/v1_2/download_file3';
    fetch(queryUrl, {
        method: 'get'
    })
        .then(function(response) {
            return response;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.error('error from api/v1_2/download_file3', err);
            reject(false);
        });
};
```

But when triggering via javascript, the file is not downloaded.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,

Avi

Answer (score 0):

Get a blob and then you can use

```
function downloadFile(blob, fileName)
{
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style = "display: none";

    var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.href = url;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}
```

or using jquery

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: requestUrl,
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'datatype-here'
}).done(function(data) {
    var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "image/png; encoding=utf8" });
    saveData(blob, 'filename.png');    
});
```

Comment: - Would this also work if the file is very large, and the client has not much memory?  
  
- In the example, when using plain javascript with blob and createObjectURL, or when using jquery with data,
does the data have to be formed in memory before being downloaded to the file system?